# How I can change a variable in a div in a CSS, using SASS?

Tags: css, sass, styles

I wonder if there is any way to change the assignment of a variable inside a div.
Viewing the code, I think it is more visible what I want:

```
 ## CSS ##
.div-name-1 {
  $cor: #f00;
}

.div-name-2 {
  $cor: #d1d1d1;
}

.div-name-3 {
  $cor: #fff;
}

.whatever{
  background: $cor;
}
```

```
<div class="div-name-2>
<div class="whatever">
</div>

<div class="div-name-3>
<div class="whatever">
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I *think* that you would have to do it like http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/0e3c950c42ef6da7ed04e31df279bd64

Comment: Well, I have some categories, and for each one I want colors specifies for each one. 
But are a lot of divs, and I don't want write 
.div-name-3 {
  $cor: #fff;
  .whatever{
    background: $cor;
  }

.whatever-2{
    background: $cor;
  }

.whatever-3{
    background: $cor;
  }
}

for each div. You understand me?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, variables in SASS are scoped to the block they appear in. Since `.div-name-1` and `.whatever` are different blocks, they are different scopes and cannot transfer values of variables between them.

You will need to reorganize your SASS code so they are in the same block, or introduce a mixin in order to create the same effect:

```
.div-name-1 {
  $cor: #f00;

  .whatever {
    background: $cor;
  }
}

.div-name-2 {
  $cor: #d1d1d1;

  .whatever {
    background: $cor;
  }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
@mixin whatever($cor) {
  .whatever {
    background: $cor;
  }
}

.div-name-1 { @include whatever(#f00);  }
.div-name-2 { @include whatever(#d1d1d1); }
```

Comment: But, are a lot of divs, and I want change not just the color, but the background, color-border... The one way is do a big code? 
For example. I have a title h1, a button, any element with border, and according with the father-div, this elements will be differents.

Comment: All I'm telling you is that you cannot adjust variables the way you are trying to. Using a mixin does not seem like "big code". Usinga  mixin allows you to create a reusable chunk of code (which it appears you are trying to do). If your mixin needs more parameters because you want to manipulate more than just the color, then add more parameters. Seems like you are giving up on any alternative solutions just because you want SASS variables to work in a way they are not designed to work.

Comment: You might even want to try using map of properties and create a SASS loop through your divs if they are all numbered that way.

Comment: Oh, ok. Make sense. I'm sorry, but, I thought that this would be like javascript. 
Like pass a parameter for a function, and according com this parameter, the variable change.
But, after your explanation, I understand how do this (: 

thanks